# Getting error while creating common service using IONIC NativeStorage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 6 NativeStorage to store the data locally and getting error while creating common service for setting and getting the storage.

if the `deviceinfo` key not set and trying to store JSON data.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error"
```

Below is the sample code,

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/native-storage/ngx';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonServicesService {
    constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
 }

    function getStorage() {
          return this.nativeStorage.getItem('deviceinfo').then((deviceObj) => {
                //if the key exists then return
                if (deviceObj) {
                    try {
                        return deviceObj;
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //set the storage
                    let dataobj = { "institutionid": "2", "firstname": "", "nickname": ""};
                    this.nativeStorage.setItem('deviceinfo', JSON.stringify(dataobj));
                    return true;
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log("Getting Promise error"))
    }
}
```

And calling from another component,

```
this.commonServices.getStorage().then((deviceobj: any) => { 
   console.log(deviceobj);
})
```

can any one help to write common service?

Comment: are you using capacitor or Cordova? if your are using Capacitor try this plugin: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage

Comment: Thanks Najam. But I am using Cordova plugin. can you please help on this

Comment: why not put some proper console.log inside  catch (err) {} so what we can see where error is coming from.

Comment: @mahen, getting the Promise error if the storage not set initially i.e, deviceinfo key not exists initially. Actually am trying to set the value if the data is empty.